# How do you pass pointers to an external library?

Tags: dll, rebol, rebol2

Question.  When using external libraries, is there the same `pointer!` in Rebol2 as there is in Red/System?

If the c declaration were:

```
void f (int* i);
```

How would I define the `routine!`?

```
f: make routine! [
    "Does Something"
    int [pointer! [integer!]]
    return: [char!]
] lib "f"
```

I see http://rebol.com/docs/library.html#section-25

> "External library functions that are passed pointers, generally expect
>   the pointers to be char or void datatypes. Currently, REBOL routines
>   do not support the void datatype. In most cases, you can safely pass
>   char instead of void. For return values, use long instead of void."

However, just a little confused.  What is the correct way to define the routine for `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the link states

```
f: make routine! [
  "Does Something"
  pInt [char*]
  return: [long]
] lib "f"
```

worked for me a few years ago

Comment: I ended up needing to use `int` instead of `char*` to get my library to work.